# ESLint react/prop-types warns about value missing in validation. But it's present?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-proptypes

Type `React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>` contains the definition for `value`. I'm just extending it with `ProductsLimitChoiceProps` but ESLint complains. Can you see anything wrong here?

> ESLint: 'value' is missing in props validation

```typescript
import React from 'react';

type ProductsLimitChoiceProps = React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement> & {
  limits?: (string | number)[],
  onChange?: (value: string) => any,
}

export const ProductsLimitChoice = ({
  value,
  onChange = () => {},
  limits = [5, 10, 15, 20],
  ...props
}: ProductsLimitChoiceProps) => {
  return (
    <select className="select select-primary"
      value={value} onChange={({ target }) => onChange(target.value)} {...props}>
      {limits.map(v => <option key={v} value={v}>{v}</option>)}
    </select>
  );
};
```